# how to add in a new thread without stopping the program?

Tags: python, multithreading, loops, python-asyncio

```
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import time

async def commands_update():
    for x in range(1000):
        if x == 50:
            executor.submit(add_thread_function())
        print(x)


def add_thread_function():
    while True:
        print("added new thread")
        time.sleep(1)


with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=None) as executor:
    executor.submit(asyncio.run, commands_update())
```

how do i add a new thread without waiting for the add_thread_function() to complete? the program basically will not complete since the add_thread_function() is a while loop. i need to make it such that if x reaches 50, it'll create a new thread without stopping. or should i redesign my codes? i'm very clueless right now .. :(

Comment: You never create any thread with `commands_update`, because the argument to `executor.submit()` is a function call that never completes. Write it like this and try again: `executor.submit(add_thread_function)`

Comment: are you required to use ThreadPoolExecutor and asyncio or could you use threading? I don't know about ThreadPoolExecutor but I could give you a working example for threading, using a class.

Comment: You should redesign.